# Preciso de ajuda Variavel i

Tags: java

Preciso de ajuda nesta questão:

Escreva uma função passoAPasso (), que imprime 5 vezes o conteúdo de i . Por exemplo:

```
passoAPasso()
“01234”
```

Faça um console.log(valor) para cada iteração.

Fiz a fórmula:

```
function passoAPasso()

{for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log(“01234”)
}}
```

mas ele retorna:

> Sua solução não passou as provas*
>
> Imprimir passoAPasso() deveria imprimir 01234 [Ver detalhes]
>   ‘01234\n01234\n01234\n01234\n01234\n’ == ‘0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n’

Poderiam me auxiliar?

Answer (score 1):

Sua Função está próxima, o loop `FOR` está correto, porém você deveria colocar o valor de i que está sendo mudado dentro da função para imprimir no console.

Seu código deveria ficar assim:

```js
function passoAPasso()
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }

//chamando a função para testar
passoAPasso();
```

Explicando o laço `FOR` que foi feito nessa função:

- Começando em 0 (i = 0), o laço for será executado;
- Depois da execução o valor  de i será acrescido em 1 (i++) ;
- O laço só será executado enquanto o valor de i for menor que 5 (i < 5);
- OBS: A função irá exibir no console cada número separado por uma quebra de linha;

---

Caso queira que o laço `FOR` imprima os resultados na mesma linha, sugiro que declare uma variável do tipo `string` (texto) e no laço `FOR`, coloque os números dentro desse texto e só mostre o valor dessa variável após o laço `FOR` ser executado.

Nesse caso, seu código deveria ficar assim:

```js
function passoAPasso()
{
  var resultado = ""; //valor em branco
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    resultado = resultado + i; //aqui faço a concatenação do texto antigo e o valor atual de `i`
  }
  console.log(resultado); //após o fechamento do for, posso fazer o uso do resultado
}

//chamando a função para testar
passoAPasso();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta concatenar o valor em uma string:

```js
var resultado = ''

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    resultado += String(i)
}

console.log(resultado)
```